# Parse words from textbox

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, words

I want to parse the content of my text_box to verify if my text contain each words of my textbox.

```
var answer = listanswer.Where(x => x.description.Contains(TextBox_1.Text));

if (answer.Count() == 1)
{
    Interaction question = answer.First();
    foreach (Choice choice in question.choices)
    {
        if (choice.status == "correct")
        {
            lb_input.Items.Add(choice.text);
        }
    }
}
```

Actually I check the total content of my text_box, I'm looking for a way to verify each words.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the text by white-space, then you can use `Enumerable.All`:

```
string[] words = TextBox_1.Text.Split();
var answer = listanswer.Where(x => words.All(w => x.description.Contains(w)));
```

Comment: +1. @biokstor - idea - look up [Enumerable.All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) and look at sample. Pay close attention to "Namespace:System.Linq" line - you need correct `using` and that line will tell you what namespace to use.